# Java, lazily initialized field without synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization, lazy-evaluation

Sometimes when I need lazily initialized field, I use following design pattern.

```
class DictionaryHolder {
  private volatile Dictionary dict; // some heavy object

  public Dictionary getDictionary() {
    Dictionary d = this.dict;
    if (d == null) {
      d = loadDictionary(); // costy operation
      this.dict = d;
    }
    return d;
  }
}
```

It looks like Double Checking idion, but not exactly. There is no synchronization and it is possible for `loadDictionary` method to be called several times.

I use this pattern when the concurrency is pretty low. Also I bear in mind following assumptions when using this pattern:

- `loadDictionary` method always returns the same data.
- `loadDictionary` method is thread-safe.

My questions:

1. Is this pattern correct? In other words, is it possible for `getDictionary()` to return invalid data?
2. Is it possible to make `dict` field non-volatile for more efficiency?
3. Is there any better solution?

Comment: I'm interested in the "best" answer too, but couldn't you put a synchronized block in the null test since that occurs rarely?

Comment: @Andrew, what do you mean by "null test"?

Comment: @Anrey: inside if (d==null); something like if (d==null) { sync(this) { if == null { d = loadDict() } }; I might as well go ahead and make this an answer...

Comment: @Andrew, synchronization is what I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: @Anrey; but if synchronization block is used so rarely that it can only happen once; what does it matter?

Comment: @Andrew, good note. If concurrency is low, my approach looks simpler.

Comment: Well at least nobody mentioned "dependency injection". yuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Is this pattern correct? In other words, is it possible for getDictionary() to return invalid data?

Yes if it's okay that `loadDictionary()` can be called by several threads simultaneously and thus different calls to `getDictionary()` can return different objects. Otherwise you need a solution with syncronization.

> 2.Is it possible to make dict field non-volatile for more efficiency?

No, it can cause memory visibility problems.

> 3.Is there any better solution?

As long as you want a solution without syncronization (either explicit or implicit) - no (as far as I understand). Otherwise, there are a lot of idioms such as using `enum` or inner holder class (but they use implicit synchronization).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to rely on the fact that a class is not loaded until it is needed. i.e. it is lazy loaded anyway. This way you can avoid having to do those checks yourself.

```
public enum Dictionary {
 INSTANCE;

  private Dictionary() {
     // load dictionary
  }
}
```

There shouldn't be a need to make it any more complex, certainly you won't make it more efficient.

EDIT: If Dictionary need to extend List or Map you can do.

```
public enum Dictionary implements List<String> { }
```

OR a better approach is to use a field.

```
public enum Dictionary {
    INSTANCE;
    public final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

OR use a static initialization block

```
public class Dictionary extends ArrayList<String> {
    public static final Dictionary INSTANCE = new Dictionary();
    private Dictionary() { }
}
```

Comment: I may not understand how enums work at the class-loading level but wouldn't this be loaded when the parent class is loaded? Kinda like a static variable in which case it isn't too lazy.

Comment: My code above is simplification. In real cases Dictionary is, for example, List.

Comment: @Andrew, this is true, if you want to use the Class `Dictionary` but don't want to use it instance, then you may need a different approach (or a rethink of what you are doing ;)

Comment: what if Dictoinary is actually ArrayList<SomeHeavyObject>? How can I make it enum?

Comment: If you want to use an enum, you need one called DictionaryHolder with an INSTANCE which has a Dictionary as a field.

Answer (score 3):

I personally feel that the [Initialization on demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) is a good fit for this case. From the wiki:

```
public class Something {

        private Something() {}

        private static class LazyHolder {
                private static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
        }

        public static final Something getInstance() {
                return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

Though this might look like a pattern intended purely for singleton control, you can do many more cool things with it. For e.g. the holder class can invoke a method which in turn populates some kind of data.

Also, it seems that in your case if multiple threads queue on the loadDictionary call (which is synchronized), you might end up loading the *same* thing multiple times.

Comment: Yes, this works well, but also adds a new class instance into PermGen! I have tired to increase permgen size for my Tomcat :)

Comment: I personally feel that this is a pretty good bargain for an additional class added to permagen. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. To avoid loading more than once, `synchronized{}` would be nice.

You can remove `volatile`, if `Dictionary` is immutable.

```
private Dictionary dict; // not volatile; assume Dictionary immutable

public Dictionary getDict()
    if(dict==null)
        dict = load()
    return dict;
```

If we add double checked locking, it's perfect

```
public Dictionary getDict()
    if(dict==null)
        synchronized(this)
             if(dict==null)
                  dict = load()
    return dict;
```

Double checked locking works great for immutable objects, without need of volatile.

---

Unfortunately the above 2 `getDict()` methods aren't theoretically bullet proof. The weak java memory model will allow some spooky actions - in theory. To be 100% correct by the book, we must add a local variable, which clutters our code:

```
public Dictionary getDict()
    Dictionary local = dict;
    if(local==null)
        synchronized(this)
             local = dict;
             if(local==null)
                  local = dict = load()
    return local;
```

Comment: Will non-volatile Dictionary instance be visible for other threads?

Comment: @Andrey thread1 will create an instance (which thread1 is guaranteed to see) if thread1 fails to see another instance created earlier by thread2. now if it's required that only one instance can be created, we can use double checked locking - it is safe for immutable object, without using volatile.

Comment: this is true if all fields of Dictionary class are final. AFAIK, if some fields are not final, that thread1 may see Dictionary instance created by thread2 but without some fields initialized.

Comment: @Andrey that's what I meant in "if `Dictionary` is immutable."

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick stab at this but what about...

```
class DictionaryHolder {
  private volatile Dictionary dict; // some heavy object

  public Dictionary getDictionary() {
    Dictionary d = this.dict;
    if (d == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        d = this.dict;
        if (d == null) { // gated test for null
          this.dict = d = loadDictionary(); // costy operation
        }
    }
    return d;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly Double Checked Locking, which the OP wants to avoid, and which is obsolete anyway.

Comment: This is called double checked locking, and it is broken in java.  (works fine for C#)  http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Your code illustrates perfect Double Checking design pattern. In my case requirements are not very strong - loadDictionary is allowed to be called several times - and I avoid the synchronization.

Comment: @karoberts: according to that link using volatile in Java 1.5+ it works. @Andrey: yeah, I didn't know this was called double checking locking but I'll leave my answer up for discussions on the topic. (I've already learned something)

Comment: @Péter Török: no, that's exactly **NOT** the DCL because it's unedited answer has *dict* being volatile.  Now of course *dict* being volatile means that it's not answering the OP's question, which wants to avoid synch cost.  But it's definitely not the DCL.

Comment: you missed something, the second check `d==null` is always true.

Comment: @irreputable: I think you missed the point of the double gated check

Comment: it's a local variable, which was null, and not set to a new value. so it's still null.

Comment: @irreputable: fixed, based on the wiki page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make dict field non-volatile for more efficiency?

No. That would hurt *visibility*, i.e. when one thread initializes `dict`, other threads may not see the updated reference in time (or at all). This in turn would results in multiple heavy initializations, thus *lots* of useless work <strike>, not to mention returning references to multiple distinct objects</strike>.

Anyway, when dealing with concurrency, micro-optimizations for efficiency would be my last thought.

Comment: it doesent matter, OP has clearly stated that loadDictionary returns the same object always

Comment: if without volatile, lack of visibility is not a problem - each thread is guaranteed to return a non-null reference. it's the premature visibility that is the problem - thread 1 may see the reference set by thread 2 before construction is finished. that problem goes away if `Dictionary` is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize-on-demand holder class idiom**

> This method relies on the JVM only
>   intializing the class members upon
>   first reference to the class. In this
>   case, we have a inner class that is
>   only referenced within the
>   getDictionary() method. This means
>   DictionaryHolder will get initialized
>   on the first call to getDictionary().

```
public class DictionaryHolder {

  private DictionaryHolder ()
  {
  }

  public static Dictionary getDictionary() 
  {
     return DictionaryLazyHolder.instance;
  }

  private static class DictionaryLazyHolder
  {
    static final DictionaryHolder instance = new DictionaryHolder();
  }
}
```